# Is prostrating an act of worship?

Tags: ibadah, sajda, prostration

Would the act of prostrating (making sajda) be worship in of itself?

I have been thinking about this issue and I would say it does not because Prophet Yaqoub did it to his son Prophet Yousef.

However, I'm curious to see if anyone holds a different view and WHY do you hold that view?  Evidences are the main issue.

Please don't say it was a different Shari'ah, as this itself has no evidence.

Comment: There is a prostration of respect and prostration of worship. You would have to define worship first before you answer this question. Also an elaborate discussion spirituality is also required ie what is spirit and spirituality.

Comment: An act would only be worship if the person believes the divinity of an object.  Like the difference between a Muslim prostrating to an idol vs a mushrik is that the later believes the idol is god or at least divine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all of the discussions I've had regarding prostration, I've concluded the following =

- There's no sufficient evidence from Quran and Sunnah explicitly saying prostration is an act of worship in of itself.
- If prostration was worship, every Muslim would be worshiping the thing in front of them.  There would be no Muslims left on earth.
- The angels would've been worshiping Prophet Adam.
- Prophet Yaqoub and his family would be worshiping Prophet Yousef.
- Rasolullah himself would be worshiping the Kaba.

So from the lack of explicit evidence and the rational conclusions, prostration is NOT and act of worship in of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o alaikum ya akhi,

This is a good question. I will mention few points insha'Allah and you are to decide as I am not a scholar,

- Please see [Tafseer](http://allahu-ahad.org/?go=12:100&taf=1) of the ayah, specially فقال إني رأيتهم يسجدون
  لأساقفتهم وأنت أحق
- "Nay! (O Muhammad (Peace be upon him))! Do not
  obey him (Abu Jahl). Fall prostrate and draw near to Allah!" [Quran
  96:19](http://allahu-ahad.org/?go=96:19&tid=8123&tdir=lr&tclass=)
- Angels prostrated to Adam on command of Allah SWT as form
  of worship (worship not to Adam, but by obeying command of Allah SWT) - [by way of bowing as a sign of respect to him, not by putting the forehead](http://allahu-ahad.org/?go=18:50&taf=1&tafid=1595&tafdir=lr&tafclass=)

Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Yes, prostration is an act of worship in itself.

The reason is quite simple. If you see someone prostrating in front of someone or something, there is no doubt in our mind that he is worshipping.

Over the period of generations, certain acts have become so universally associated with worship, that they are now in-separable.

If you look at differents act of worship in Haj, you will notice that all the acts of worship that humans have constructed to worship any deity, Allah has individualized them for Himself. e.g. circling of Kaaba, shaving of head etc

Comment: Something is worship because Allah tells us.  We're not the ones to decide what act is worship.  Therefore, do you have evidence from Quran or Sahih Hadith that mentions sajda is worship?